# Show Google Spreadsheet name into a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I want to know a Googlesheet app script I can use to show or copy the spreadsheet name into a cell. For example, I wish to show or copy the spreadsheet name into cell A1. And value of A1 also update as soon as I renamed the spreadsheet name and hit return as Im using Mac. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
function SPREADSHEETNAME() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
}
```